# How to enable vi mode in Monodevelop on windows

Tags: monodevelop, vi

I searched for a while, and I found a vi mode, but I don't know how to enable it in ModeDevelop(opened from Unity).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For the people who are still looking for the answer, you can enable vi mode using following menu option

`Edit` → `Preferences` → `Text Editor` → `Behavior` → `Navigation (use vi modes)`

Older versions may have used

`Tools` → `Options` → `Text Editor` → `Behavior` → `Navigation (use vi modes)`

Comment: The same for Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Fair warning: Support is bleak. Hardcore vim-ers should probably stick to vim.

Comment: Yeah, both '3dd' and 'dd.' deleted only a single line, when I tried it on MonoDevelop 5.9.6 (Ubuntu). I think I'll look for a Unity3D plugin for vim, instead.

Comment: Is anyone aware of a way to modify the key bindings for vi mode? I use dvorak, so I like to remap the basic navigation keys...

Answer (score 0):

Mac Users menu item is: MonoDevelop-Unity / Preferences (or Command-;)
Text Editor / Behavior
Navigation : User Vi modes