# How to enable vi mode in Monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, vi

How can i enable the vi mode in MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2 on Linux?
I found this:
[How to enable vi mode in Monodevelop on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897987/how-to-enable-vi-mode-in-monodevelop-on-windows)
but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

While the screenshot shown is on Mac, it should hold true on Linux too.
Under `Preferences`, select `Behavior` (Behaviour for us non-Americans) and check off `Navigation > Use Vi modes`.

[image]